Is there any way to optimize loading of a large number of groups with items in DataGrid? WinUI3
I have implemented logic for grouping items in DataGrid, but I am facing a problem that when there are a large number of items, my UI hangs and takes a very long time to render the table.
C# Grouping:
private ICollectionView GroupDuplicates()
        {
            var groups = new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoCollection<DuplicateItem>>();

            var duplicatedFiles = FilesCollection.Cast<DuplicateItem>();

            var allDuplicates = GetAllDuplicates(duplicatedFiles);

            var query = GetQueryBySortingType(allDuplicates);

            foreach (var g in query)
            {
                var info = new GroupInfoCollection<DuplicateItem>();
                info.Key = g.GroupName;

                foreach (var item in g.Items)
                {
                    info.Add(item);
                }

                groups.Add(info);
            }

            var sorted = SortGroup(groups);

            var groupedDuplicates = new CollectionViewSource();
            groupedDuplicates.IsSourceGrouped = true;
            groupedDuplicates.Source = sorted;

            return groupedDuplicates.View;
        }

XAML:
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="DuplicatesDataGrid"
                   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                   CanUserSortColumns="True"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   ItemsSource="{x:Bind DuplicatesSource, Mode=OneWay}"
                   LoadingRowGroup="DuplicatesDataGrid_LoadingRowGroup"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                   Margin="0,0,10,0"
                   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                   ColumnWidth="*"
                   RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
    <controls:DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="BodyTextBlockStyle"
               TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                    Value="16" />
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridRowGroupHeaderBackgroundBrush"
                         Color="#ffffff"
                         Opacity="0.0605" />

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonTemplate"
                         TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Grid Background="Green">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Arrow.Glyph"
                                        Value="{ThemeResource RowGroupHeaderIconClosed}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Arrow.Glyph"
                                        Value="{ThemeResource RowGroupHeaderIconClosed}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Arrow.Glyph"
                                        Value="{ThemeResource RowGroupHeaderIconClosed}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="Arrow.Glyph"
                                        Value="{ThemeResource RowGroupHeaderIconClosed}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled" />
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow"
                          FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                          Glyph="{ThemeResource RowGroupHeaderIconOpened}"
                          FontSize="12"
                          Foreground="{ThemeResource DataGridRowGroupHeaderForegroundBrush}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </controls:DataGrid.Resources>
    <controls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
        <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
            <Setter Property="PropertyNameVisibility"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter Property="ItemCountVisibility"
                    Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Transparent" />
        </Style>
    </controls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
    <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding CommonResources.FilenameText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
                                         CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridItemStyle}"
                                         x:Name="FileNameColumn"
                                         CellTemplate="{StaticResource DuplicateFileNameColumnTemplate}"
                                         HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DuplicateDataGridNameHeaderStyle}"
                                         Tag="FileName">
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding CommonResources.SizeText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
                                         x:Name="SizeColumn"
                                         HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridSizeHeaderStyle}"
                                         CellTemplate="{StaticResource DuplicateFileSizeColumnTemplate}"
                                         CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridItemStyle}"
                                         Tag="SizeText">
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding CommonResources.LastModifiedText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
                                         HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridDateHeaderStyle}"
                                         CellTemplate="{StaticResource DuplicateFileDateColumnTemplate}"
                                         x:Name="DateColumn"
                                         CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridItemStyle}"
                                         Tag="LastModifiedText">
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding CommonResources.FileLocationText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
                                         CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridItemStyle}"
                                         CellTemplate="{StaticResource DuplicateFilePathColumnTemplate}"
                                         HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridPathHeaderStyle}"
                                         x:Name="FilePathColumn"
                                         Tag="FileLocationText">
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
</controls:DataGrid>

Xaml.cs:
 public static readonly DependencyProperty DuplicatesSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(DuplicatesSource),
            typeof(ICollectionView),
            typeof(ScanResultsView),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public ScanResultsView()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ICollectionView DuplicatesSource
        {
            get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(DuplicatesSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DuplicatesSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        private void DuplicatesDataGrid_LoadingRowGroup(object sender, DataGridRowGroupHeaderEventArgs e)
        {
            ICollectionViewGroup group = e.RowGroupHeader.CollectionViewGroup;
            var duplicate = group.GroupItems[0] as DuplicateItem;

            e.RowGroupHeader.PropertyValue = duplicate.Name;
        }

I tried passing as a source an AdvancedCollectionView  type that supports IncrementalLoading, but as it turns out it doesn't support grouping items together. I also tried to implement custom loading by parts, the idea was to add a handler for LoadingRowGroup event and check when N pages are loaded and add more items. But it failed because of the following error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Items cannot be added, removed or reset while rows are loading or unloading.'
Is there any way to optimize loading of a large number of groups with items in DataGrid ?

The DataGrid is not very performant handling large number of items. It might not be what you want but try the ListView instead.
